# Finding intersection

Tags: java, arrays, intersection

I have to find the intersection between two Set objects.

Comment: What is the type of the parameter? Your `Set` class or `java.util.Set`?

Comment: Why was the actual implementation edited away? The question makes hardly any sense in the current form.

Answer (score 3):

The variable `intCount` is local in the innermost `if`-condition, which means that only the first entry of `interArr` is accessed. Rearrange the implementation as follows.

```
public int[] intersection(Set parSet)
{
    int[] interArr = new int[numbers.length];
    int[] testArr = parSet.toArray();

    int intCount = 0; // initialization out of the loop

    for(int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++)
    {
        for(int compareInt = 0; compareInt < testArr.length; compareInt++)
        {
            if(numbers[index] == testArr[compareInt])
            {
                interArr[intCount] = testArr[compareInt];
                intCount++;
            }//end if
        }//end inner for
    }//end outter for

    return interArr;
}//end method intersection
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track: using a nested loop to do an exhaustive search (although it could be simplified using java collection), only some minor issues:

**1)** you didn't define `toArray()` method for your class, so assume you meant `parSet.numbers` when you call `parSet.toArray()`

**2)** the counter `intCount` needs to be outside of the loop to avoid being set to 0 in every iteration.

So the correct version should be:

```
public int[] intersection(Set parSet) {
    int[] interArr = new int[numbers.length];
    int[] testArr = parSet.numbers; //you didn't define toArray() for the class Set
    int intCount = 0; // move this variable out of the loop
    for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
        for (int compareInt = 0; compareInt < testArr.length; compareInt++) {
            if (numbers[index] == testArr[compareInt]) {
                interArr[intCount] = testArr[compareInt];
                intCount++;
            }//end if
        }//end inner for
    }//end outter for

    return interArr;
}//end method intersection
```